# How do I use numbers inside of a ListBox as variables?

Tags: vb.net, listboxitem

I'm extremely new to coding so bare with me. My problem is that i'm trying to make a if statement that basically states the after a certain age, if you have no tickets, you're rate will be blank. So far This is what i got

```
        Dim Ticket As String = txtYorNo.Text.ToString
        Dim Rate As Double = 0
        If lstAge.SelectedItems > 30 And Ticket = "n" Then
            Rate += 30
```

my problem is that i can't declare lstage.selecteditem as a double and i want to do that but it keeps telling me the error "object" cannot be converted into Double. How can i make it that i can use the listbox number list as a variable.

Comment: First of all, assuming `txtYorNo` is a TextBox and/or `.Text` is a string, then `.ToString` is redundant. Second, you're using `SelectedItems`, not `SelectedItem`. If you're certain that the ListBox items will always be integers, you can use `DirectCast(lstAge.SelectedItem, Integer)` or `CInt(lstAge.SelectedItem)`. One more thing, you should always favor `AndAlso` over `And` when dealing with booleans.

Comment: So how would it appear in a if statement? I'm new to this so i don't know what directcast does. I'm trying to make it that if the person selects let say 20 and the condition is 30 and above, how would i state that in a if statement

Comment: I'm fairly certain `DirectCast` is documented in the online help.  You can get there by pressing F1.  If you do so with `DirectCast` highlighted, it should take you directly to help on it.